# Trouble setting up the Zend_Loader_Autoloader. Pretty easy question, but I'm new to Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload

Read the comments in the code for a description:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
public function __construct($configSection){
        $rootDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
        define('ROOT_DIR',$rootDir);

        set_include_path(get_include_path()
        . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR . '/library/'
        . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR .
        'application/models'
        );

        //PROBLEM LIES HERE, BEWARE OF DRAGONS.
        //Using this, I receive a deprecated warning.
        include 'Zend/Loader.php';
        Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();        

        //Using this, I recieve an error that autoload() has missing arguments.     
        //Zend_Loader_Autoloader::autoload();       

        //Load the configuration file.
        Zend_Registry::set('configSection', $configSection);
        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(ROOT_DIR . '/application/config.ini',$configSection);

        Zend_Registry::set('config',$config);
        date_default_timezone_set($config->date_default_timezone);

        //Database configuration settings go here. :)
        $db = Zend_Db::factory($config->db);
        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
        Zend_Registry::set('db',$db);
    }

    public function configureFrontController(){
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $frontController->setControllerDirectory(ROOT_DIR . '/application/controllers');
    }

    public function runApp(){
        $this->configureFrontController();

        //Runs the Zend application. :)
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $frontController->dispath();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to follow a tutorial that wants me to configure my Zend app to use the autoloading functions that it offers.

When using the registerAutoLoad() method, I receive a deprecated warning and it tells me to use another method, the one below it in my code.

What can I do?

**Edit: Why I was using the deprecated method:**

> One less than ideal aspect of the
>   bootstrap file in the original Hello
>   World is that there are a lot of
>   Zend_Loader::loadClass() calls to load
>   up the classes we need before we use
>   them.
>
> In larger applications, there are even
>   more classes in use, resulting in
>   clutter throughout the application
>   just to ensure that the right classes
>   are included at the right time.
>
> For our Places website, we use PHP’s
>   __autoload() functionality so that PHP will automatically load our classes
>   for us. PHP5 introduced the
>   __autoload() magic function that is called whenever you try to instantiate
>   a class that hasn’t yet been defined.
>
> The Zend_Loader class has a special
>   registerAutoload() method specifically
>   for use with __autoload(), as shown in
>   listing 3.1 b. This method will
>   automatically use PHP5’s Standard PHP
>   Library (SPL) spl_autoload_register()
>   function so that multiple autoloaders
>   can be used.
>
> After Zend_Loader::registerAutoload()
>   has been called, whenever a class is
>   instantiated that has not yet been
>   defined, the file containing the class
>   is included. This solves the problem
>   of Zend_Loader::loadClass() clutter
>   and ensures that only the needed files
>   are loaded for any given request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [Autoloading was changed in ZF1.8](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend_loaders-autoloader_deprecated-in-zend-framework-18/) you should replace

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

with

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace('App_');
```

or use the fallback autoloader with

```
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
$loader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(false);
```

Depending on the age of your tutorial, I suggest checking out the [tutorial for the recent ZF1.10 at Rob Allen's blog](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-tutorial-for-zf-1-10/) as well.